# How to make radio button group collapsable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sort of a menu bar, which consists of radio buttons (in a button group) that I designed as buttons using bootstrap. Now I would like to make it responsive, so that they would collapse into a dropdown button, when the window would be narrow enough. I couldn't find anything alike in the bootstrap documentation, so I have no idea how to achieve this - any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div style="clear: both; display: inline;">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm active" style="width: 300px;"><input type="radio"  value="0" class="check" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>1</label>
            <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="width: 300px;"><input type="radio" value="1" class="check" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">2</label>
            <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="width: 300px;"><input type="radio" value="2" class="check" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make use of `@media screen` in CSS and change the width and height of div , If is that what you want

Comment: I also want to arrange buttons (labels) into a dropdown menu, can I also do that through `@media screen`?

Comment: try this i think its working you http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div style="clear: both; display: inline;">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="collapse">
            <div class="dropdown-button-container">
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm active" style="width: 300px;"><input autocomplete="off" checked class="check" id="option1" name="options" type="radio" value="0">1</label> <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="width: 300px;"><input autocomplete="off" class="check" id="option2" name="options" type="radio" value="1">2</label> <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="width: 300px;"><input autocomplete="off" class="check" id="option3" name="options" type="radio" value="2">3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).on("load, resize", function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 768) {
        $(".dropdown-button-container").addClass("collapse");
    } else {
        $(".dropdown-button-container").removeClass("collapse");
});
```

That's about as specific as I can get with the info provided.